# How can I create an external SSL wrapper/tunnel page for an insecure webpage behind a firewall?

Tags: linux, ssh, ssl, stunnel

I have an security cam with a built-in webpage inside my home network.  That camera is using basic HTTP authentication instead of SSL.  I want to be able to access the camera's webpage from outside my network, but I don't want to open an unencrypted video stream to the outside world.

Right now, I'm doing some cumbersome ssh tunneling where I bounce off an ssh server like:

```
ssh -N -L 9090:CAMERA_IP:80 ross@mynetwork.dnsalias.com
```

and then I connect to my web page like:

```
http://localhost:9090
```

But this is a pain.

Now, gentle reader, I beseech you to tell me how I can use linux (Ubuntu) to get a **fully** encrypted SSL connection to my internal web page without the hassle of creating an ssh tunnel each time.

I believe I can use [stunnel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stunnel), but I'm not sure of the command.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file on mynetwork.dnsalias.com with the content (use the defualt stunnel.conf file as the starting point):

```
accept  = MY_PORT
connect = CAMERA_IP:80
```

Then allow incoming connections from MY_PORT, and you should be able to use SSL to my_port to connect.

Comment: I'll give that a try.